# Are there conjectured closed forms for factorial rational zeta series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, conjectures

**Context**
At the bottom of [this](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiemannZetaFunction.html) page from Wolfram Mathworld on the [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function), the following constants are defined in equations (133), (137), and (141), respectively:

\begin{align*} C_{1} &:= \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(n)}{n!} \\ 
& \approx 1.078188729575818482758265436769832381707219, \\\qquad C_{2} &:= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2n)}{n!} \\ 
& \approx 2.407446554790328514709486656223022725582266, \text{ and} \\  C_{3} &:= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\zeta(2n)}{(2n)!} \\
&\approx 0.869001991962908998811054805561395688892494.\end{align*} It is also stated that "These sums have no known closed-form expression".

However, it could be the case that there are *conjectured* closed forms for these constants that correspond to the actual values with a high degree of accuracy.

**Question**: Are there any of such conjectured closed forms for $C_{1}$, $C_{2}$, and $C_{3}$ ?

Comment: For the first one I conjecture $e^{-31/48-23/(48e)+e/24-5/(24\pi)-7\pi/48}\pi^{23e/48-1/6}\sqrt[24]{-\tan(\pi e)}=1.078188729575818482\dots$ :)

Comment: $$C_1  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{{e^x  - 1}}\left[ {\frac{{I_1 (2\sqrt x )}}{{\sqrt x }} - 1} \right]dx}$$

Comment: @Gary Indeed, such formulas are also stated on the Mathworld page (see eq. 134)

Comment: @MaxMuller Oh, I should have checked it.